# If Yom Kippur seals our fate, why do we pray the rest of the year?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year

If on *Yom Kippur* on fate is sealed, why do we continue to be *mispalleil* for the rest of the **year**?

Answer (score 0):

Prayer is the means through which the שפע comes into the world. I believe there is a medrash that says that the plants were waiting for Adam to pray before they broke out of the soil.